# AWS LAMBDA function "Cannot read property 's3' of undefined"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using lambda AWS to convert mp4 to HLS and when I put my hostname: I am getting an error of the following:

```json
{

"errorType": "TypeError",
  "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 's3' of undefined",
  "trace": [
    "TypeError: Cannot read property 's3' of undefined",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:14:35)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

line 14 inputBucket = `eventRecord.s3.bucket.name`,

My output is set in Lambda to which bucker I want to post to.

Any idea?

Comment: Please include the relevant code. Clearly there is a problem at line 14 of your Lambda function, where you are trying to access the `s3` property of an undefined object reference.

Comment: inputBucket = eventRecord.s3.bucket.name,

Comment: You should generally include enough code to repro the problem. I can't see how you are initializing `eventRecord` but it has an undefined value.

Comment: please check the code here

Comment: Assuming you were attempting to link to a code repository:  Please don't.  The question should be [mre], meaning it should be self contained and not require looking at external sites for more clues.

Comment: exports.handler = function (eventObject, context) {
    const eventRecord = eventObject.Records && eventObject.Records[0],
        inputBucket = eventRecord.s3.bucket.name,
        key = eventRecord.s3.object.key,
        id = context.awsRequestId,
        resultKey = key.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, EXTENSION),
        workdir = os.tmpdir(),
        inputFile = path.join(workdir, id + path.extname(key)),
        newfile = key.substr(0, key.lastIndexOf("."));
        iconFile = path.join(workdir, "sample.m3u8"),

Comment: When adding code, edit the original post rather than adding it via comments. Debug your code by logging the values of `eventObject.Records` and `eventObject.Records[0]`.

Comment: Note: if you are using the Lambda console and a test event to trigger your Lambda then you need to [structure the test event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#test-manual-invoke) correctly to match the S3 event.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the event your Lambda function is not a [valid S3 event](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html#test-manual-invoke).

At a guess, you are manually triggering your Lambda function with a test event from the AWS console and you have supplied an non-conformant JSON structure.

Here is a minimal example of what you need in the test event:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "s3": {
        "bucket": {
          "name": "my-s3-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```